# Is passing asyncio.Future through multiprocessing.Queue and back thread-safe?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

If I pass `asyncio.Future` (along with input data) to a `Process` using `multiprocessing.Queue`, then pass it back along with result data through a result queue into current thread (and asyncio loop that created the future), then call `future.set_result()` there - is it thread-safe? Or is it more correct to use `concurrent.futures.Future` for this purpose?

Comment: Is an asyncio future even serializable? It contains a reference to the event loop. I would create a future and a unique identifier (a monotonically increasing integer would do), associate the future with the identifier, pass the identifier to the other process. When the calculation is done, I'd pass the identifier back along with the result, look up the future by the identifier, and call `set_result()` on that.

Comment: @user4815162342 I think using `asyncio.wrap_future()` and passing around concurrent future (as `ProcessPoolExecutor` and `loop.run_in_executor()` in standard library do) would be more explicit if we would go this way, my question is more of a "what if we pass future directly", but yeah, now I'm interested if it can even survive serialization.

Comment: Well, it's far from obvious to me that a `concurrent.futures.Future` would survive a serialization roundtrip either. Even if it looks like it does, be careful that what you get back isn't a deep copy of the future, i.e. an unrelated future object. What I propose in the previous comment is fool-proof and guaranteed to always work.